# Does jQuery have any requirements in server side

Tags: jquery, requirements

Does jQuery have any requirements in server side?

I installed a same script in 2 domains 2 servers all are same except the domain name, when I browse the sites I see the jQuery works in one and not working in another where I am using the same computer and same browser .

Comment: only requirement is to have the jquery js files accessible to the browser. they can be hosted on a CDN, so they don't have to even be on any of the servers.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? jQuery runs on the client side in the browser and doesn't even need a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is a Javascript library. JavaScript hosted on web pages are executed on the client side. Therefore, jQuery can work even without the use of a server. You just need the file.

If the library is not working on a site,it is usually because this site makes a function call that leads to an exception being raised. Usually, you can't detect those by opening the development tools or your browser (F12 on IE and Chrome for example). There is a console that logs everything abnormal in the execution of the script. You can even debug the Javascript code there. Look it up. I'm certain there will be an exception there and this is what makes jQuery not work on that site.

Comment: Actually problem was in php short tags which was not enabled in non-working site

Thanks